# how to compile and run ExampleCallIn for asterisk-java using javac and java

Tags: java, compilation, runtime-error, classpath, asterisk

I'm just trying to compile the example for [java-asterisk](https://github.com/srt/asterisk-java):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ cp /home/thufir/.m2/repository/org/asteriskjava/asterisk-java/1.0.0/asterisk-java-1.0.0.jar asterisk-java.jar -v
‘/home/thufir/.m2/repository/org/asteriskjava/asterisk-java/1.0.0/asterisk-java-1.0.0.jar’ -> ‘asterisk-java.jar’
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ javac -cp asterisk-java.jar ExampleCallIn.java
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ java -cp asterisk-java.jar org.asteriskjavafastagi.DefaultAgiServer
Error: Could not find or load main class org.asteriskjavafastagi.DefaultAgiServer
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ cat ExampleCallIn.java 
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiChannel;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiException;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiRequest;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.BaseAgiScript;

public class ExampleCallIn extends BaseAgiScript {

    @Override
    public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel) throws AgiException {
        answer();
        exec("Playback", "tt-monkeys");
        hangup();
    }
}
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ cat fastagi-mapping.properties 

hello.agi = ExampleCallIn

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

see also:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.telephony.pbx.asterisk.java/11

-----------------------------------------------------------------------result

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ javac -cp asterisk-java.jar ExampleCallIn.java
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ java -cp asterisk-java.jar org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer
Apr 20, 2015 12:19:20 PM org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer startup
INFO: Listening on *:4573.
^Cthufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAsterisk/src$
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
java -cp asterisk-java.jar org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer
```

your command seems missing the dot in `asteriskjavafastagi`

Comment: thanks, I updated the question to show the result.  That's the desired result?

Comment: looks like it, you might need to check this link [tutorial](https://maven.reucon.com/projects/public/asterisk-java/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/asterisk-java/tutorial.html)